# How to create an independent indexer with default value inside ngRepeat loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of posts with comments. I need to traverse through array of comments inside each of the posts on my page. I'm trying to create variable inside ngRepeat for posts which I can use like an indexer to display exact comment for each post. Due to ngRepeat creating nested scope, this variable must be unique for each iteration. But when I'm trying to change it with ng-click, it doesn't change.

My ngRepeat:

```
<div class="question_block col-xs-12" 
                         ng-repeat="answer in question.content.answer track by answer.id">
```

is followed by `<span style="display:none">{{counter=0}}</span>`. And then I'm showing some items like `<span>{{answer.comments[counter].user.organization.title}}</span>`. When I'm trying to do something like `<a href ng-click="counter++">Increment</a>` nothing happens. What's the matter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-init="counter = 0"` and attach your `ng-click` to a function in your controller:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" ng-init="counter=0">
  {{item}} ({{counter}})
  <button ng-click="clickHandler()">Increment</button> 
  <hr />
</div>
```

Then, to increment `counter` in the context of the event, use `this.counter`

```
$scope.clickHandler = function() {
 this.counter++;
};
```

Plunker demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/J4d0JlJSKD7i4OfMT2r4?p=preview

Comment: Ty for idea, I was trying to do the same with function to increment, but passing index as a parameter did no good. The key is using _this_ to address current scope variable.